# regular expression that extract consecutive words in a sentance

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to find a regular expression in java that will extract pairs of consecutive words 
in a sentance, like in the example below.

**input**: word1 word2 word3 word4 ....

**output**:

- word1 word2
- word2 word3
- word3 word4

etc..

any idea how to do that ?

Comment: Use `String.split("\\s+")` and work from there.

Comment: I don't see how a regex can work here. If you match two words, the next match the regex will find after that will be the words that are after the two first matched words. So your first match would be "word1 word2", the next match will be "word3 word4". The split idea mentioned by Marko seems like a better solution.

Comment: @FrancisGagnon The technique in regex is to capture a match from the zero-width lookahead (like in Omega's solution). It's a technique worth being aware of in general, even if it's not a good fit for this particular problem.

Comment: @Marko Agreed. It is an interesting technique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Java code:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?:^|(?<=\\s))(?=(\\S+\\s+\\S+)(?=\\s|$))")
  .matcher("word1 word2 word3 word4");
while (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

#### Output:

```
word1 word2
word2 word3
word3 word4
```

Test this code **[here](http://ideone.com/TIv5bT)**.

Comment: Is there a way to extend and express this for N words?
For example, 3 consecutive words uses a central capture group of (\\S+\\s+\\S+\\s+\\S+) which is formed by just adding another space and word, but I get the feeling regex could be used to quantify the number of words (N)?  I have tried adding {3} but it is not working, so I am reduced to building a regex string by concat, which seems very clunky.

Comment: @SteveHibbert - Sure, use the following pattern with `{N-1}` quantifier (for N=3, N-1=2): [Test here](https://ideone.com/ih88M3) `Pattern.compile("(?:^|(?<=\\s))(?=((?:\\S+\\s+){2}\\S+)(?=\\s|$))")`

Comment: That is fantastic, works a treat.  I can now pull out variable blocks of words in a loop, and that gives me word frequency analysis for groups of words.  I cannot thank you enough, I am much obliged to you.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String words = "word1 word2 word3 word4";
        String regex="\\w+\\s+\\w+";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = p.matcher(words);
        while(matcher.find()){
            String found = matcher.group();
            System.out.println(found);
            String splitted = found.split("\\s+")[1];
            words = words.replace(found, splitted);
            matcher = p.matcher(words);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Too offer a solution without unjustified complexity...

```
final String in = "word1 word2 word3 word4";
final String[] words = in.split("\\s+");
for (int i = 0; i < words.length - 1; i++)
  System.out.println(words[i] + " " + words[i+1]);
```

prints

```
word1 word2
word2 word3
word3 word4
```

Answer (score -1):

There you go: -

```
"\\w+\\s+\\w+"
```

One or more word, then one or more space, and then one or more word.

---

**UPDATE : -**

Just noticed that the above regex misses your second line of output. 
So you can just split your string on `space`, and work with your array.

```
String[] words = str.split("\\s+");
```

And then get word for every pair of indices.

Comment: This will miss OP's second line of output.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik.. Yeah, didn't notice that.

Comment: you will get word1 word2 then word3 word4 ,etc..not what i'm looking for.

Comment: @AtaiVoltaire.. Yeah, I took care of that part.